# How to open applications after booting a purely Command line interface of Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

After booting linux in purly command line mode how can I open an application eg web browser or Libra Office?

For example if I use the command "play" with any audio file it starts to play it. I want to know commands for other applications

Comment: You don't "open" applications on the command line, you "run" them. And most web browsers or LibreOffice need a destop, or at least an X11 environment. So start your X11 server with `startx`

Answer (score 1):

You have to start an X Window session before you can open those applications because they depend on it to render the GUI. To do this you can use the `startx` command.

There is a good description here on how to use [startx](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/runningx.html).

However, doing it this way can be a lot of manual and tedious work. That's why most linux distros have packaged full window managers like Gnome, Xcfe, etc for you to install with a single command. If what you really want is a minimal one you might look at [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/%E2%80%8E) or [Openbox](http://openbox.org/). You can learn a lot about the guts of X by installing and configuring them on your own.

I suspect what you may really need is just to edit text files and get resources from the internet while logged into a Linux box that is command line only. If so, you can check out these command line only tools.

- [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) command line browser
- [WGet](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) internet file retriever
- [EMacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) text editor
- [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) text editor